# How Do I Access The API Response From Stripe, When Creating A Customer

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I am a total newbie. I understand some PHP. I have been able to create a customer in Stripe.
I need to save the customer id (cus_123..) in my database.

- Where exactly is the "response" to my API when I create a customer?
- How do I access the response and specifically the customer id, so I
  can save it in my database for future use?

The code I used to successfully create a non paying customer in Stripe:

```php
include ('config.php'); // this will fetch my secret keys

$fullname = 'James Doe'; // passing the name variable
$email = 'james@test.com'; // passing the email variable

// create Stripe Customer                   
\Stripe\Customer::create([
    'description' => 'Guest',
    'name'=> $fullname,
    'email'=> $email
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the Stripe [API Documention: Customer Creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php), you can access the data in the return response from your API call.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'description' => 'Guest',
    'name'=> $fullname,
    'email'=> $email
]);
// Customer ID
echo $customer->id;
```

You should wrap this call in a `try {} catch( .. ){ }` call as it may throw an error, as-per documentation.

Comment: Could you kindly show me how to use try { } catch (..) I tried a few different ways and kept getting error messages.

Comment: @DC-9 `try { my code above } catch(Exception $e){ print_r($e); }`. You can learn more by reading the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Still creating customers, but getting error messages. I tried the Try, catch in different configurations. didn't work.

Comment: $fullname = 'James Doe';
   $email = 'james@test.com';
   
 try{ // create Stripe Customer     
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
   'description' => 'Guest',
   'name'=> $fullname,
   'email'=> $email
   ]);  

   echo $customer -> id;
   }
   
   catch (Exception $e)
    { print_r($e); };

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Darren, I spent several days looking for a way to do this. The final code below echoed the customer id.

```
                $fullname = 'James Doe';
        $email = 'james@test.com';

try{    // create Stripe Customer                   
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'description' => 'Guest',
        'name'=> $fullname,
        'email'=> $email
        ]);

        echo $customer -> id;
        }

        catch (Exception $e)
            { print_r($e); };
```